# Named Ranges deleted on update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, oledb, named-ranges

I have an excel file which I'm using as my backend (I have no control over this choice) and I've created my named ranges. I'm using OLEDB to connect to the sheets from my application in VB.Net.

However,once i update any of the sheets from my application, ALL my namedranges are deleted and the application stops working. This doesn't happen if I'm just reading from the workbook. Anyone experienced this and any possible ideas or solutions?